# Azure Service Bus Java SDK - unable to update the QueueInfo with forwardTo another entity, gives me 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, servicebus

Getting 500 Internal Server error when trying to update forwardTo property on a QueueInfo object. Am able to update the QueueInfo seperately with other features maxSizeInMB, partitioning etc.. but doesnt work with forwardTo(anotherQueue). Will it not work if i want to forward from first queue to second queue ? Both the Queues are intact and have the manage permissions

Results in the below exception:

> 10:19:46.603 [main] WARN com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract - com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT https://vccrgnsc8d109902b.servicebus.windows.net/queue1_5f6943857f24?api-version=2013-07 returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT https://vccrgnsc8d109902b.servicebus.windows.net/queue1_5f6943857f24?api-version=2013-07 returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error

The code i am trying to execute :

```
Configuration config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication("vccr‌​gnsc8d109902b", "RootManageSharedAccessKey", "fIDkggkN+eOpIMzbdIL7kmqBB5m5Ub983KmQiw4iyD8=", ".servicebus.windows.net"); 
ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config); 
GetQueueResult resultQueue1 = service.getQueue("queue1_5f6943857f24"); 
GetQueueResult resultQueue2 = service.getQueue("queue2_e0c541758865"); 
QueueInfo q1Info = resultQueue1.getValue(); 
q1Info.setForwardTo("queue2_e0c541758865"); 
service.updateQueue(q1Info);
```

Comment: The code am trying to execute : 

Configuration config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication("vccrgnsc8d109902b", "RootManageSharedAccessKey", 
"fIDkggkN+eOpIMzbdIL7kmqBB5m5Ub983KmQiw4iyD8=", ".servicebus.windows.net");

ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);
GetQueueResult resultQueue1 = service.getQueue("queue1_5f6943857f24");

GetQueueResult resultQueue2 = service.getQueue("queue2_e0c541758865");

QueueInfo q1Info = resultQueue1.getValue();
q1Info.setForwardTo("queue2_e0c541758865");

service.updateQueue(q1Info);

Comment: 10:52:49.408 [main] WARN com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract - com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT https://vccrgnsc8d109902b.servicebus.windows.net/queue1_5f6943857f24?api-version=2013-07 returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT https://vccrgnsc8d109902b.servicebus.windows.net/queue1_5f6943857f24?api-version=2013-07 returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.h

Comment: Could you possibly edit your code snippets to use the formated text features in MarkDown to make them more readable?

Comment: I tried to format (like spacing etc..) but somehow it doesnt take

Comment: Try back ticks: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting
... Edit: NVM, I see you worked it out :)